# How to add a link to Outlook on email in people result search?

Tags: 2013, people-search

I display the email of person when I search people.

I want  to add a link to Outlook on email in people result search.

I want to know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom display template, render the email address in an Anchor tag with the mailto: protocol.

```
<a href="mailto:person@example.com">person@example.com</a>
```